# RegEx with backreference (capture last if possible)

Tags: c#, regex

I have a RegEx-Problem which is hard to describe, so I will show an example:

```
<A>example <B>text <A>more text</A></B></A> defg <A attr="value">Test</A>
```

Each `<A>` can have attributes.

I try to get the following matches:

```
<A>example <B>text <A>more text</A></B></A>
<A attr="value">Test</A>
```

---

Currently I use this RegEx:

```
<(?<TAG>\w*)\b.*?>.*?(</\k<TAG>>)
```

but the Capturing-group ends at the first `</A>` for the first group.

```
<A>example <B>text <A>more text</A>
<A attr="value">Test</A>
```

Comment: Regex for HTML/XML parsing. Make it stop for once and for all!

Comment: Quoting the regex tag summary: "Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using."

Comment: I use RegExBuddy if this answere your question ... Target programming language is C#.

Comment: Use an XML parser. Seriously.

Comment: You should do this using an XML parser (or an [HTML parser](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com) if this is actually HTML).